# SIgnalR- not use singleton pattern

Tags: c#, singleton, signalr

In my application, I am sending real-time updates to each client based on his subscriptions. 
So e.g. if a client is subscribed to items 1,2 & 3 he should only see updates from these items while at the same time if another client is subscribed to items 4,5 & 6 then he should be able to receive real-time updates for those items. 
My problem is as soon as I connect with the second id `SignalR` forgets about the old group and starts notification of new ids only.
I guess it's because there's only one instance of real-time updates is running and it's being shared among all connected clients. 
 Is there a way that each connected client has its own instance of a real-time object?

```
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    private readonly RealTimeData data;

    public DataHub() : this(RealTimeData.Instance) { }

    public DataHub(RealTimeData rdata)
    {
        data = rdata; //can I instantiate RealTimeData object here?
    }

    public void Start(Int64 routerId)
    {
        data.StartTimer(routerId);
    }
}

public class RealTimeData
{
    private readonly static Lazy<RealTimeData> _instance = new Lazy<RealTimeData>(() => new RealTimeData(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataHub>().Clients));  //will avoiding this create a separate instance for each client? 
    private IHubConnectionContext Clients;

    public Timer timer;
    private readonly int updateInterval = 1000;
    private readonly object updateRecievedDataLock = new object();
    private bool updateReceivedData = false;
    List<Items> allItems = new List<Items>();
    private RealTimeData()
    {
    }

    private RealTimeData(IHubConnectionContext clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }

    public static RealTimeData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer(Int64 routerId)
    {
        this.routerId = routerId;
        timer = new Timer(GetDataForAllItems, null, updateInterval, updateInterval);
    }

    public void GetDataForAllItems(object state)
    {
        if (updateReceivedData)
        {
            return;
        }
        lock (updateRecievedDataLock)
        {
            if (!updateReceivedData)
            {
                updateReceivedData = true;
                //get data from database
                allItems = Mapper.Instance.GetDataForAllItems(routerId);
                updateReceivedData = false;
                //send it to the browser for update
                BroadcastData(allItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a new instance in the constructor of RealTimeData would create an instance of the class each client call, so the singleton would normally be correct. Have you look at Group subscriptions in SignalR v2, as it seems they would meet your requirement. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Answer (score 1):

I think you are attacking the problem from a wrong angle. Instead of polling the DB each second let the action that saves to the DB publish a message on a message bus that you forward to the Clients.

Have a look at this library,

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library

Answer (score 1):

Group subscriptions in SignalR v2 are handled by using the `this.Groups.Add` and `this.Groups.Remove` methods in the Hub > HubBase ancestor class.

These methods could be used to subscribe to group 1,2,3 or 4,5,6 in your example by using something like this.

```
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    public async Task Register(int groupNumber)
    {
        await this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupNumber.ToString());
    }

    public async Task Unregister(int groupNumber)
    {
        await this.Groups.Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupNumber.ToString());
    }
}
```

On the client this would be called by passing a group number to the Register/Unregister methods. An example might be:

```
this._DataHub.Invoke("Register", "1");
```

From you RealTimeData singleton or other business class that publishes the update, you would reference `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataHub>()` and call then use `.Clients.Group("1").<clientMethod>` to invoke the client-side method.

For example:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataHub>();
hubContext.Clients.Group("1").UpdateDisplay("New tweet");
```

To read up a bit more of this have a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview

I hope this answers the question.